# UWP - Rich Edit Box throws exception when get or set multi-line text while math mode API is enabled

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox, math-mode

I have a `RichEditBox` in `UWP`. I've enabled math mode API using the following statement.

```
LimitedAccessFeatures.TryUnlockFeature(...);
RichEditBox.TextDocument.SetMathMode(RichEditMathMode.MathOnly);
```

When I type multi-line in this `RichEditBox` and call `RichEditBox.TextDocument.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out string rtf)` and `RichEditBox.TextDocument.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, value)`, it throws the following exception.

> **System.AccessViolationException:** 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'

It also has the same behavior in multi-line when using `RichEditBox.LoadFromStream(...)` and `RichEditBox.SaveToStream(...)`.

---

And also when I type multi-line in this `RichEditBox` and call `RichEditBox.TextDocument.GetMath(out string math)`, `math` returned an empty string. It works properly for single-line, but not multi-line.

---

### To reproduce this

1. Enable math mode API in `RichEditBox`.
2. Set `AcceptsReturn` property to `true`.
3. Type some multi-line text in `RichEditBox`.
4. Call these following statements in that `RichEditBox`.

   1. `RichEditBox.TextDocument.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out string rtf)`
   2. `RichEditBox.TextDocument.SetText(TextSetOptions.FormatRtf, value)`
   3. `RichEditBox.LoadFromStream(...)`
   4. `RichEditBox.SaveToStream(...)`

---

### What I've tried:

I figured out how to get a rich text from that `RichEditBox` using the following statement.

```
RichEditBox.TextDocument.SetMathMode(RichEditMathMode.NoMath);
RichEditBox.TextDocument.GetText(TextGetOptions.FormatRtf, out string rtf);
RichEditBox.TextDocument.SetMathMode(RichEditMathMode.MathOnly);
```

It works properly for `RichEditBox.TextDocument.GetText(TextGetOptions, out string)` method. But it doesn't work for `RichEditBox.TextDocument.SetText(TextSetOptions, string)` because if I call it, it sets only a line but not any characters. That means all character is set as `'\0'` and line as `'\n'`.

Comment: What kind of support do you think math mode has for new lines?

Comment: I want to get the rich text of `RichEditBox` to tear the tab view using `CoreWindow/ApplicationView` in `UWP` (`AppWindow` is in preview and has limited features) and also save and open file matters. Because I can save files with `*.rtf`, but not `*.mml` on multi-lines.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same behavior using `SaveToStream` and `LoadFromStream`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry to mention about `SaveToStream` and `LoadFromStream`. It also has the same behavior.